# Mudar a class do link tooltip

Tags: css, link, tooltip

Caros, boa tarde.

Tenho o link tooltip definido como:

```
 <a class="evento color-red" href="#"><span>informação</span>link</a>
```

Tem  como deixar dessa maneira e manter os atributos tooltip:

```
<a class="evento" href="#"><span>informação</span>link</a>
```

Esse css retirei da internet.

```css
.evento,
.cancelar_presenca,
.musicaistooltip,
.cancelar_evento
 {
 position: relative !important;
 display: inline-block !important;
 text-decoration: none !important;    
 }
 
.evento span,
.cancelar_presenca span,
.musicaistooltip span,
.cancelar_evento span,
.css-tooltip-diagonal-right span,
.css-tooltip-diagonal-left span
 {
 min-width: 180px;
 font-family: arial, sans-serif !important;
 font-size: 13px !important;
 line-height: normal !important;
 text-align: left !important;
 padding: 10px 10px 12px 10px !important;
 visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 9999999 !important;

 -webkit-transition-duration: 0.25s;
 -moz-transition-duration: 0.25s;
 -o-transition-duration: 0.25s;
 -ms-transition-duration: 0.25s;
 transition-duration: 0.25s;
 -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.35,0,0.35,1);
 -moz-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.35,0,0.35,1);
 -o-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.35,0,0.35,1);
 -ms-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.35,0,0.35,1);
 transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.35,0,0.35,1);
 }

.evento span:before,
.cancelar_presenca span:before,
.musicaistooltip span:before,
.cancelar_evento span:before,
.css-tooltip-diagonal-right span:before,
.css-tooltip-diagonal-left span:before
 {
 content: "";
 display: block;
 width: 0px;
 height: 0px;
 position: absolute;
 }

/* Tool tip Top */
.evento span
 {
 left: -10px;
 bottom: 100%;
 margin-bottom: 30px;
 
 -webkit-transition-property: opacity, margin-bottom, visibility;
 -moz-transition-property: opacity, margin-bottom, visibility;
 -o-transition-property: opacity, margin-bottom, visibility;
 -ms-transition-property: opacity, margin-bottom, visibility;
 transition-property: opacity, margin-bottom, visibility;
 }
 
.evento span:before
 {
    border-left: 8px solid transparent !important;
    border-right: 8px solid transparent !important;
 border-top: 8px solid #000;
 border-bottom: 0 !important;
 bottom: -8px;
 left: 15px;
 }

.evento:hover span
 { 
 margin-bottom: 10px; /* End Position */
 visibility: visible;
 opacity: 1;
 }

 
/* tooltip left
-------------------------------------------------------------- */

.cancelar_evento span
 {
 right: 100%;
 top: -7px;
 margin-right: 35px;
 
 -webkit-transition-property: opacity, margin-right, visibility;
 -moz-transition-property: opacity, margin-right, visibility;
 -o-transition-property: opacity, margin-right, visibility;
 -ms-transition-property: opacity, margin-right, visibility;
 transition-property: opacity, margin-right, visibility;
 }
 
.cancelar_evento span:before
 {
    border-left: 8px solid #000;
    border-right: 0 !important;
 border-top: 8px solid transparent !important;
 border-bottom: 8px solid transparent !important;
 top: 11px;
 right: -8px;
 }

.cancelar_evento:hover span
 { 
 margin-right: 15px;
 visibility: visible;
 opacity: 1;
 }
 
/* tooltip right
-------------------------------------------------------------- */

.musicaistooltip span
 {
 left: 100%;
 top: -7px;
 margin-left: 35px;

 -webkit-transition-property: opacity, margin-left, visibility;
 -moz-transition-property: opacity, margin-left, visibility;
 -o-transition-property: opacity, margin-left, visibility;
 -ms-transition-property: opacity, margin-left, visibility;
 transition-property: opacity, margin-left, visibility;
 }
 
.musicaistooltip span:before {
    border-left: 0 !important;
    border-right: 8px solid #000;
 border-top: 8px solid transparent !important;
 border-bottom: 8px solid transparent !important;
 top: 11px;
 left: -8px;
 }

.musicaistooltip:hover span
 { 
 margin-left: 15px;
 visibility: visible;
 opacity: 1;
 }
 
 
/*tooltip bottom
-------------------------------------------------------------- */

.cancelar_presenca span
 {
 left: -10px;
 top: 100%;
 margin-top: 30px;
 
 -webkit-transition-property: opacity, margin-top, visibility;
 -moz-transition-property: opacity, margin-top, visibility;
 -o-transition-property: opacity, margin-top, visibility;
 -ms-transition-property: opacity, margin-top, visibility;
 transition-property: opacity, margin-top, visibility;
 }
 
.cancelar_presenca span:before
 {
    border-left: 8px solid transparent !important;
    border-right: 8px solid transparent !important;
 border-top: 0 !important;
 border-bottom: 8px solid #000;
 top: -8px;
 left: 15px;
 }

.cancelar_presenca:hover span
 { 
 margin-top: 10px;
 visibility: visible;
 opacity: 1;
 }
 
/* Tooltip Color */
.color-blue span
 {
 color: #ffffff !important;
 
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.75) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.75) 100%);
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.75)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,0.75))); 
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.75) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.75) 100%);
 background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.75) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.75) 100%);
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.75) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.75) 100%);
 background: linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.75) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.75) 100%);

 -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
 -moz-border-radius: 4px;
 border-radius: 4px;
 
 text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
 }

.color-blue span:before
 {
 border-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
 }
 
.color-blue span:after
 {
 content: "";
 display: block;
 border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
 position: absolute;
 left: 0px;
 top: 1px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 10px;
 
 -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
 -moz-border-radius: 4px;
 border-radius: 4px;
 }
 
.color-green span
 {
 color: #ffffff !important;
 
 
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.75); 
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.75) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.75) 100%); 
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.75)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,0.75))); 
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.75) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.75) 100%); 
 background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.75) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.75) 100%); 
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.75) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.75) 100%); 
 background: linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.75) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.75) 100%); 
 
 -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
 -moz-border-radius: 4px;
 border-radius: 4px;
 
 
 text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
 }


.color-green span:before
 {
 border-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
 }
 

.color-green span:after
 {
 content: "";
 display: block;
 border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
 position: absolute;
 left: 0px;
 top: 1px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 10px;
 
 
 -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
 -moz-border-radius: 4px;
 border-radius: 4px;
 }
 

.color-green span strong
 {
 background: #246407;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #205a06;
 }
 
/*orange*/

.color-orange span
 {
 color: #ffffff !important;
 
 
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.75); 
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.75) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.75) 100%); 
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.75)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,0.75))); 
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.75) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.75) 100%); 
 background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.75) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.75) 100%); 
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.75) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.75) 100%); 
 background: linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.75) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.75) 100%);
 
 -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
 -moz-border-radius: 4px;
 border-radius: 4px;
 
 
 text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
 }


.color-orange span:before
 {
 border-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
 }
 

.color-orange span:after
 {
 content: "";
 display: block;
 border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
 position: absolute;
 left: 0px;
 top: 1px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 10px;
 
 
 -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
 -moz-border-radius: 4px;
 border-radius: 4px;
 }
 

.color-orange span strong
 {
 background: #bf461a;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #ac3f17;
 }
 
 /*red*/

.color-red span
 {
 color: #ffffff !important;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.75); 
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.75) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.75) 100%); 
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.75)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,0.75))); 
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.75) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.75) 100%); 
 background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.75) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.75) 100%); 
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.75) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.75) 100%); 
 background: linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.75) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.75) 100%); 
 -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
 -moz-border-radius: 4px;
 border-radius: 4px;
 text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
 }
.color-red span:before
 {
 border-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
 }
.color-red span:after
 {
 content: "";
 display: block;
 border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
 position: absolute;
 left: 0px;
 top: 1px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 10px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
 -moz-border-radius: 4px;
 border-radius: 4px;
 }
.color-red span strong
 {
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
 border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
 }
```

```html
<br><br><Br><Br><a class='evento color-red' href="#" class='meu_evento'><span>informação</span>link</a>
```

Por favor, alguém pode me ajudar?

Muito obrigado.

Comment: olá, você pode testar usando $('a.evento').removeClass('color-red'), porém para uma melhor analise coloque o código da tag body, ou altere para ter mais precisão de identificação o "a.evento" para o que for mais viável.

Comment: Me passaram esse código:

Comment: <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.event > span').hide(); // Get the direct descendant of all elements with classname 'event'
});

$(function() {
  // Bind the click event to the anchors with classname 'event'
  $(".event").click(function() {

    // Fade in the SPAN inside the anchor
    $(this).find('> span').fadeIn();

    // The other stuff
    var commentContainer = $(this);
    var id = $(this).attr("id");

    alert("The value is "+id);

return false;
 });
});

</script>

Mas não mantém o tooltip e o efeito JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Com jQuery você consegue

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

<script>
$(function() {

$(".evento").addClass("evento color-red");

 });
</script>

<a class="evento" href="#"><span>informação</span>link</a>
```

Você vai pegar o elemento e vai trocar pela classe completa para funcionar o script.